# Split data into two bootstrap columns with knockout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I use a Bootstrap carousel to display two columns of data in each carousel item. This is a simplified example of what i'm doing:

```
<div class="carousel-inner col-sm-12" role="listbox" data-bind="foreach: { data: dataSlides, as: 'slide' }">
    <div class="item" data-bind="css: { active: $index() == 0 }">
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: { data: dataLeft, as: 'data' }">
            <div data-bind="text: data"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: { data: dataRight, as: 'data' }">
            <div data-bind="text: data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the data model i have, uses this structure:

```
self.dataSlides = ko.observableArray(
[
    { dataLeft: ['data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3'], dataRight: ['data 4', 'data 5', 'data 6'] },
    { dataLeft: ['data 7', 'data 8', 'data 9'], dataRight: ['data 10', 'data 11', 'data 12'] }
]);
```

This works as expected but with one problem. The part where i display my data `<div data-bind="text: data"></div>` is quite complex in my real implementation and as you can see, i have to write it 2 times. Once for my left data and once for my right data.

> What i would like to do, is to put my data in just one data array (no dataLeft/dataRight) and display half of my data in the left column and the other half in the right column. This way i would not have to write the data display loop twice.

To do this I need to somehow close and reopen the column tag when the foreach is through half of the data. I tried the following but this does not work because it breaks the foreach:

```
<!-- ko if: $index() == data().length / 2 -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<!-- /ko -->
```

How can i do this?

Comment: also `data().lenght / 2` won't work because `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 1):

I think that modifying your data to simplify the view and data-binds isn't a bad idea. You just shouldn't do it manually.

A good approach to these kind of problems is to work with two variables:

1. The (observable) data *source*: in your case, an array of slides
2. One or more data "representations": an automatic (`computed`) version of the data that filters, sorts or restructures it to match your view purposes.

So, for your case, I'd propose a `ko.pureComputed` variable that:

1. Watches the original data source and automatically computes,
2. `x` rows with each `y` columns with each `z` slides.

A sample implementation (not the "smartest" way to do it, I tried to make it easy to read... and don't mind the styling):

```js
var dataSlides = ko.observableArray(["slide 1","slide 2","slide 3","slide 4","slide 5","slide 6","slide 7","slide 8","slide 9","slide 10","slide 11","slide 12"]);

var dataTable = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var rows = [];
  var slidesPerCol = 3;
  var colPerRow = 2;
  var slidesPerRow = slidesPerCol * colPerRow;
  
  dataSlides().forEach(function(slide, index) {
    var rowNr = Math.floor(index / slidesPerRow);
    var colNr = Math.floor((index % slidesPerRow) / slidesPerCol);
    
    rows[rowNr] = rows[rowNr] || getRow(colPerRow);
    rows[rowNr][colNr].push(slide);
  });
  
  return rows;
});

ko.applyBindings({ 
  dataTable: dataTable, 
  pushSlide: function(){
    dataSlides.push("slide " + dataSlides().length);
  }
});

// Util
function getRow(c, s) {
   return Array(c)
     .fill(null)
     .map(function() { return []; }); 
}
```

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.col + .col { border-left: 1px solid black; }

.slide {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: { data: dataTable, as: 'row' }" class="table">
  <div data-bind="foreach: { data: row, as: 'col' }" class="row">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: col, as: 'slide'}" class="col">
      <span data-bind="text: slide" class="slide"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: pushSlide">add slide</button>
```

Comment: My data is displayed vertically not horizontal, 'data 1/2/3' is below each other. Each carousel item contains 2 columns where the data is rotated 90° to your solution.

Comment: That's more of a css change I guess... I've changed `flex-direction` to `column` which should be about right. Still, the real answer is in the `ko.pureComputed`

Comment: Since i cannot use flex because i have to support older IE versions, this is not really an option.

Comment: I was under the impression this question was about not having to write duplicate code or markup, not about CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think u should have a container for the left column and one for the right column, and foreach half the list in each ones.

Like this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/2ytouxvs/2/

```
self.dataSlides = ko.observableArray(
  [
      ['data 1a', 'data 2a', 'data 3a', 'data 4a', 'data 5a', 'data 6a'],
      ['data 1b', 'data 2b', 'data 3b', 'data 4b', 'data 5b', 'data 6b']
  ]);


<div class="carousel-inner col-sm-12" role="listbox" data-bind="foreach: dataSlides, as: 'slide'">

  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <!-- ko if: $index()+1 < $data.length / 2 -->
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-2">
    <div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <!-- ko if: $index()+1 > $data.length / 2 -->
      <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. This does not solve my problem that i have to write the display part `<div data-bind="text: $data"></div>` 2 times. In my implementation this is quite alot of code and i would like to have it only once.